# How to fix a segmentation fault with Ruby 2.0.0p645

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

While I'm  parsing alliance feed  in a Sinatra/Ruby app I get the error:

```
/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/net/http/response.rb:368: [BUG]
Segmentation fault ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
```

I'm wondering if this is a bug with Ruby or something wrong with the code, and if so, what  could I do to fix it?

[Link to the error](http://pastebin.com/F5GE55CC)

This is the code for the parsing alliance feed:

```
        feeds.each { |name, hash|
            puts "=== PARSING #{name.upcase} FEED ==="
            start = Time.now
            open(hash[:url]) { |feed|
                send(hash[:action], feed)
            }
            duration = Time.now - start
            puts "Feed syndication completed in #{duration.to_s} seconds."
            puts
        }

        # Close DB connection
        puts "Disconnecting"
        @db.disconnect
    end

    def parseAllianceData(xml)
        start = Time.now
        allianceData = XMLObject.new xml
        duration = Time.now - start

        puts "XML parsed in #{duration.to_s} seconds."
        puts "Alliances found: #{allianceData.alliances.count}"

        @db[:feeds].insert(
            :generated_at => allianceData.server.datagenerationdatetime,
            :type => "Alliance",
            :is_current => true)

        start = Time.now
        allianceData.alliances.each { |alliance|
            capital_last_moved_at = (alliance.alliancecapitallastmoved rescue nil)
            taxrate_last_changed_at = (alliance.alliancetaxratelastchanged rescue nil)
            @db[:alliance].insert(
                :id => alliance.alliance[:id],
                :ticker => alliance.allianceticker,
                :name => alliance.alliance,
                :founded_at => alliance.foundeddatetime,
                :founded_by_player_id => alliance.foundedbyplayerid[:id],
                :capital_town_id => alliance.alliancecapitaltownid[:id],
                :member_count => alliance.membercount,
                :total_population => (alliance.totalpopulation rescue 0),
                :tax_rate => (alliance.alliancetaxrate.to_i) / 100.0,
                :tax_rate_last_changed_at => taxrate_last_changed_at,
                :capital_town_last_moved_at => capital_last_moved_at)

            alliance.roles.each { |role|
                @db[:alliance_roles].insert(
                    :id => role.role[:id],
                    :name => role.role,
                    :alliance_id => alliance.alliance[:id],
                    :hierarchy_id => role.heirarchy[:id])
            }
        }
        duration = Time.now - start
        puts "Database populated in #{duration.to_s} seconds."
```

Comment: Try using Ruby 2.2.5 and see if that works.

Comment: sadly i cant do that since i am using s server (openshift) to run the code as i ran into way to many problems with gem install on my computer

Comment: Forgot to add in the post. Before it does the PARSING ALLIANCE FEED it does a PARSING PLAYERS FEED which works fine === PARSING PLAYERS FEED ===
XML parsed in 2.067214038 seconds.
Players found: 5968
Database populated in 213.937264445 seconds.
Feed syndication completed in 216.276557037 seconds.

Comment: That's often an installation problem (e.g. compiling against one version of a library but then loading a different version of it)

Comment: Can you show your gemfile.lock?  That would help us debug it. A segfault typically comes from an error in a native C extension used by a gem.

Comment: [link]https://github.com/kodabear4511/IllyriadAp/blob/master/Gemfile.lock

Comment: I was finely able to get ruby working on my laptop and i am now using the newest ruby which doesnt seem to have thing bug

Comment: Errors must not be off-site, instead, extract the pertinent part and add it to the question. We often use that information when trying to figure out the problem and making us search external sites wastes our time. Also links to external sites can rot then break, and when they do an essential debugging component is lost.

Answer (score 1):

I spot one dangerous line of code in your sample:

```
send(hash[:action], feed)
```

It takes some string from external source (`hash[:action]`) and turns it into a method call. It is very dangerous, because you never know what string you will get. There could be a string there that cannot be made into a method call so Ruby crashes.

I would suggest checking for all supported actions and calling methods explicitly. You can do it with a `case` statement, for example.

```
action = hash[:action]

case action
when 'action1'
  call_method1
when 'action2'
  call_method2
else
  puts "unsupported action: #{action}"
end
```